# Possible to put webview within imageview in android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-webview

So what i'm trying to do is put a webview within a imageview.  I essentially have a imageview that is a tv and I want to put my webview in it to simulate a user is watching the tv.

Comment: `ImageView` is not a `ViewGroup`, so you cannot put anything inside of it from that standpoint. You can use a `FrameLayout` to put the `ImageView` *behind* the `WebView`, and if the `WebView` is sized to be a bit smaller than the `ImageView`, the `ImageView` edges will be seen around the edges.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Only a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) can contain other views.
Have you tried the **android:foreground** property on the WebView?

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/tv_frame" />
```

Here's an example
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l908k.png).

Remember that WebView is a subclass of AbsoluteLayout, which is a subclass of ViewGroup, so the following XML is perfectly legal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/tv_frame">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</WebView>
```